# Paperclip has cached an old setting. How do I refresh it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I updated a thumbnail size for my Photo model.

Worked great on my local, and deployed it to production.

Unfortunately, even if I run reprocess on a specific Photo it still reprocesses to the old params.

If I check `Photo.photo.styles` it returns the correct new styles, but if I set that Photo to reprocess, it refuses to abide by the settings I applied.

How do I clear paperclip's cache? If it isn't paperclip that's caching it, what possibly could be doing that?

I'm not using delayed_jobs to do this, but I have restarted that as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solution there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by my browser caching the old style. To resolve this, I went into the haml, and added a random URI:

```
= image_tag @image.photo(:format) + "?" + rand(9999)
```

A slight hackery as my application has turned off the default timestamped URI's. Maybe that's your problem as well. Equally, I also noticed that when I tried to run refresh on a large group of objects it would fail..

Then what I did was posted this question:

[Can you identify the current dimensions of an image with Paperclip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806801/can-you-identify-the-current-dimensions-of-an-image-with-paperclip)

And made a select statement where I found whichever photo wasn't reprocessed yet, and to reprocess it. I was working with roughly 25,000 photo objects.

Comment: Thanks for reply however this doesn't seem to be the problem in my case.

Comment: Hmm.. post up your question, and comment it here. i'd be happy to take a look more into your situation specifically.

Comment: Thanks trip, I found what it was. I'm running a staging environment on the same server with the same db. Using delayed job with paperclip seemed not to be able to distinguish which application to use, specifically geometry. Thanks again!